# Xamarin Forms map pin clicked not working?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using the latest stable version of Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Forms.Maps (v1.3.1.6296) on iOS.

I created a new pin, added a Clicked event handler and added the pin to the map.

I put a breakpoint in the Pin_Clicked event handler but it does not get called when I click the pin popup.

I also tried the latest pre-release (1.3.2.6299-pre1) but no change.

Any ideas?

Here is the code

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace Kern.Client.Views
{
    public class MapView : ContentPage
    {
        public MapView()
        {
            SetupView();
        }

        private void SetupView()
        {
            MapSpan mapSpan = MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(-36.740737, 174.702464), Distance.FromKilometers(1));

            var map = new Map(mapSpan)
            {
                IsShowingUser = true,
                HeightRequest = 100,
                WidthRequest = 960,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };

            var pin = new Pin
            {
                Type = PinType.Place,
                Position = new Position(-36.742315, 174.698151),
                Label = "Title",
                Address = "Address",
            };

            pin.Clicked += (sender, args) => DisplayAlert("Tapped!", "Pin was tapped.", "OK");

            map.Pins.Add(pin);

            Content = map;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug in Xamarin.Forms 1.3.1, I believe it is not fixed in v1.3.2-pre1 yet.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
pin.Clicked += (sender, args) => {
    DisplayAlert ("Tapped!", "Pin was tapped.", "OK");
};
```

Comment: Not for me. Can't see what could be preventing it.

Comment: I have replaced the code snippet with a simplified view that replicates the issue. The only wrinkle is my main view is a TabbedPage with the MapView being one of the tabs.

Comment: Just made the MapView the main view and still no click. I also have MvvmCross in the mix as well. Will try a really basic app.

Comment: Just created a basic app, added the code above and ran. Map and pin appear. Click pin shows popup. Click popup does not fire Clicked event.

Comment: Have you updated all your packages to the pre release versions of Forms/Maps/PlayStore etc as well as updated all your Android SDKs to the latest and greatest? If so, post the whole sample code snippet and I can try at this end...

Comment: Ha - I missed the iOS part at the start - does it work on Android on yr machine? I'm just getting my iOS bits up so won't be able to test iOS until later today/weekend my time (Melb Aus)...

Comment: Next week if fine thanks. Have raised a support issue with Xamarin. There is a good example here https://github.com/raechten/BindableMapTest showing how to do this manually that provides other benefits like bindable pins, custom icons etc.